# Python omni-completion in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, omnicomplete

I tried two ways for Python omni-completion in Emacs 23:

1. Semantic in CEDET cannot parse the methods from library import. For example, I have "import os" in Python script. I want it shows everything in "os" after I type "os.".
2. rope/ropemacs. It does work, and can pull out all the methods when you type a dot after lib name. However, it is too.... slow. Every time rope is working, my Emacs freezes about 5 seconds or more.
3. ac-python.el. It works pretty fast. However, it needs manual C-c C-c to send buffer to Python shell so that it can build up the completion source. In addition, I cannot use IPython in Emacs to do this. Not convenient.

So, since both Emacs and Python are so popularly used, could anybody suggest an easy and convenient way for Python completion in Emacs? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is [anything-ipython.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs#toc12) which requires [anything](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Anything) (which can do a lot more and is highly recommended).

Comment: Can "anything" be integrated with auto-complete? Or it has to be in a separate buffer? I really like the drop-down menu of auto-complete.

Comment: Anything and auto-complete are two different interfaces. If you want autocomplete then take a look at how anything communicates with ipython and make an autocomplete interface for it. Someone may already have done it, try searching for it first.

Comment: anything-ipython also requires loading the imported libs to ipython. It is not like rope.